# What footwear (if any) is required when playing in official football games?

Tags: rules, football

When playing in official football games, can one play with bare feet, or with trainers, or do they have to wear specific football shoes?

Comment: You can wear whatever you want and even play with bare foot if you don't mind injuring your foot. Now, football shoes are designed for football. Don't you think it would be a little weird to play football wearing basketball shoes?

Comment: More information such as what type of surface you are playing on would be helpful.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the asker wants to know what footwear, if any, is mandated in an official game of football.

Comment: @studro I retracted my downvote and close-vote after reading your comment and edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

Footwear is required in all official games of football. Trainers/runners are fine - specialised football shoes/boots are not required, although you may have trouble keeping your footing on natural turf fields in trainers/runners.

[IFAB Laws of the Game, Law 4 - The Players' Equipment, Section 2 - Compulsory Equipment](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/the-players-equipment/chapters/compulsory-equipment) (emphasis added):

> The compulsory equipment of a player comprises the following separate items:
>
> - a shirt with sleeves
> - shorts
> - socks – tape or any material applied or worn externally must be the same colour as that part of the sock it is applied to or covers
> - shinguards – these must be made of a suitable material to provide reasonable protection and covered by the socks
> - **footwear**

Comment: Interesting, however, am I correct that FIFA doesn't have any further requirements for footwear? Not even for it to be suitable? So, going straight to the extremes could you play an official game (theoretically) with flip-flops? What about sandals or crocs? Or just wearing a very very oversized sport shoes? It's obviously not gonna help in winning, but still.. would it be legal?